# Edit and/or filter CSV files

Tags: qgis, csv, filter

I'm pretty new to QGIS I have a couple of questions regarding .CSV files.

1) Whenever I download and import .CSV data into QGIS, it works perfectly. I get the points and everything is peachy, but, if I edit said .CSV file in Excel, save it again and import it again, I just get the table icon in my layers (the points aren't converted to shapes).

It's as if whenever I edit my .CSV file in Excel, it won't work anymore. Anyone know how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong here? (I save the .CSV as .CSV UTF-8 and need to use semicolons as a delimiter)

2) This kinda goes hand in hand with question 1 - instead of trying to edit data in Excel, I want to filter data out in QGIS itself. How do I do this? I know this is done using expressions, but I have no experience with these.

To give a bit more context, I have a .csv file with all traffic lights within a certain area, but it contains both, active and inactive ones. I want QGIS to only 'see' the active ones as points. (editting the .CSV in Excel doesn't work - like I tried to do in question 1).

Comment: First of all: Do you mean CSV files? Second: Excel is a very bad program to edit CSV files in my opinion. It often "destroys" data by formatting it "intelligent". A good hint to work with csv files in excel is to open excel and create a new empty table. Then format all empty cells as text. Open the csv file in notepad and copy paste it to excel. Make sure data is pasted as text. This will prevent excel from reformatting and destroying your data.

Comment: Make sure you choose the correct delimiter when importing the csv to QGIS. Also make sure to choose the correct decimal separator. There is a small checkbox for this.

Comment: "Seeing" stuff is a matter of symbology. There surely is a column which indicates whether a traffic light is active or not. Use this for classified points and you're done without editing too much.

Answer (score 2):

After you have loaded the csv file into QGIS, right click the csv-layer and go to `properties`. Then search for the tab `source`. Then open the `query builder`:
[image]

Then enter the expression. It is pretty self-explanatory. E.g. `"active" = 1` This will return all active traffic lights. The inactive ones will no longer be displayed in QGIS. You can no longer access them, but they are sill in your original data. To reaccess them, you need to change the filter.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using "select by features" ,
[image]

before that you will have to save your csv as shapefile by export your data as shapefile.

after that you can choose which are the features you want to keep or to exclude, for example, if you choose "select by value" you can write the value you want to select by choosing it from the requested field (for example, write "active" under the field that tells if the traffic light is active or not, depends in your table...) 
[image]

then after  select or exclude the features, you can  export only the selected ones   and work with new layer that has only the relevant data you need.